# CSS Attribute selector when an attribute is not set (or how do I only select non disabled input[type="text"])

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using JQuery to try to select the textboxs on a form that are not disabled. My efforts have been fruitless since I don't know how to select all the input[type="text"] but also are not set to disabled.

result so far:

$('#signature INPUT[type="text"]');

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#signature INPUT[type="text"]:not(:disabled)');
```

Comment: Two posts with identical wording, five seconds within each other, but both with (slightly) different approaches. Beautiful!

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$('#signature input:text[disabled!=disabled]');
```

In english, find all input elements inside #signature which are of type text and which do not have their `disabled` attribute set to `disabled`.